# To agree in + noun - 1871 use

Tags: grammaticality

> [[Last Para](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_v_Hughes#Judgment), J Blackburn's judgment:] The difference is the same as that between buying a horse believed to be sound, and buying one believed to be warranted sound; but I doubt if it was made obvious to the jury, and I doubt this the more because I do not see much evidence to justify a finding for the defendant on this latter ground if the word “old” was not used. There may have been more evidence than is stated in the case; and the demeanour of the witnesses may have strengthened the impression produced by the evidence there was; but it does not seem a very satisfactory verdict if it proceeded on this latter ground. I **agree**, therefore, **in** the result that there should be a new trial.

Is this right? What are the similarities and differences between 'agree on' and 'agree with'?

Answer (score 2):

ngram  for *(agree in the result)* going against British English attests many examples around 1850.

With *agree in the result*, a distinction is made between the outcome and the method of reaching that outcome. For example:

> It will scarcely be necessary for me to say, that I do not profess
>   adherence to everything herein propounded, or that, where I agree in
>   the result arrived at, I always agree in the method of arriving at the
>   same.

[The Christian doctrine of sin, tr. by W. Pulsford. 1852](http://books.google.com/books?id=1yMBAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR13&dq=%22agree%20in%20the%20result%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZENfVIPrMueHsQS664CwDw&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22agree%20in%20the%20result%22&f=false)

Comment: That is interesting. Nowadays *agree with* would be the preferred choice.

Comment: In the sentence that you quote, "agree in" is used in both instances ("in the result"/(outcome?) and "in the method"), so does this mean that no distinction is being made here; that he's saying that the logic would apply even if the last two phrases are flipped (agreeing with/to the method but not necessarily with/to the result); or am I just missing something regarding the distinction that you mention (which is probably the case)?

Comment: No, you're not missing something, I was being sloppy. What I should have said is that with "agree in the result" there seems to be a greater emphasis on the object of the preposition than there is in "agree with the result", where "with" seems to belong more with the verb than with the object of the preposition. "Agree in" seemed to be appearing more often in situations where the author was trying to define the limits and extent of his agreement.  In regard to the result, I agree.